# Wordpress admin keeps redirecting to old host

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having difficulty moving over my Wordpress blog to a new host.  Every time I go to log into my wp-admin panel, it keeps redirecting me to my old installation on localhost.

I've even ran SQL queries as noted here to update my urls, http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/  but every time I go to log in, it reverts back to localhost and I have to repeat the process over again.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Check inside `wp-config.php` to see if this is set:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Replace "example.com" with your domain.

Comment: This worked.  The only thing about it was that I had to try logging in twice after that, so at first I thought I had gotten stuck in a login redirect loop.  But this is good.

Comment: *This is a comment from [user3630842](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3630842/user3630842) which was originally posted as an answer:* It is VERY important that you clear your cache, as well. Also, when moving your site, please be sure to use this script to change ALL urls in your database. https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Comment: In my case, I fixed my database settings in wp_options table for siteurl and home, but I was still getting redirected.  Putting this setting in the wp-config did work, but didn't seem like a good permanent solution.  Eventually I figured out that the caching from my hosting provider was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting this into `wp-config.php` file worked for me:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

If using HTTPS change the value for `wordpress-https_ssl_host` in the `wp_options` table.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line into `wp-config.php` config file:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/');
```